# How to list the filename from folder in different array format in php?

Tags: php

I am using this code to get my filenames in an array

```
<?php 
  $mydir = dirname(__FILE__);
  $myfiles = array_diff(scandir($mydir), array('.', '..')); 
  $arrsingleresult = str_replace('.php', '', $myfiles);
  print_r($arrsingleresult);
?>
```

and my ouput is as follows

```
Array ( [2] => array1 [3] => first [4] => ra2 [5] => ra3 [6] => ra4 [7] => ra4code )
```

But I want my outpu to be  like this

```
Array ( 2 => 'array1', 3 => 'first', 4 => 'ra2', 5 => 'ra3', 6 => 'ra4', 7 => 'ra4code' )
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: I think you're looking for `var_export()`

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular please add your comment as answer. Thank you for the help